# Javascript: return statement inside .map array function gives undefined

Tags: javascript

Returns undefined. How ever if i console.log inside the map function that prints right value.

```
const myfun = (data) => {
    data.map((elem) => {
      return elem[1]  
    });
  };
  
  
let demo = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
  
console.log(myfun(demo)); 
// gives undefined
// should give 2 2
```

Comment: `myFun` doesn't have a `return` statement. Either add one or remove the `{` and `}` from the body.

Comment: `myFun` could be written on one line: `const myFun = (data) => data.map(elem => elem[1])`. This will implicitly return the result of `data.map(...)`

Comment: `const myfun = (data) => data.map((elem) => elem[1])` one line answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your function returns nothing, therefore undefined.

I think what you meant to write was this.

```js
const myfun = (data) => (
    data.map((elem) => {
      return elem[1]  
    })
);
```

**notice** how the `myfun` function is not using curly braces instead it's using regular brackets.

or this.

```js
const myfun = (data) => data.map((elem) => {
      return elem[1]  
    })
```

If you use curly brackets on an anonymous function you must explicitly use the `return` keyword.

Comment: Regular brackets are not needed.

Comment: Yes, they are not required I've included an example without them. sometimes however you do need them. in case you are returning an object literal `const x = () => ({})` .

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you need to return the map, not just what is mapped

```js
const myfun = (data) => {
    // You need to return the map
    return data.map((elem) => {
      return elem[1]  
    });
  };
  
  
let demo = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
  
console.log(myfun(demo));
```